# Why didn't vampires interact with Robert before sending Ruth in?

Tags: novel, i-am-legend

I just finished the book *I Am Legend* and there's something that I don't understand and can't seem to find an answer to.

> In the end we find out that there is a new living vampire society.
>
>  Now if those living vampires are intelligent enough to form a society why didn't they approach Robert before sending in Ruth? I mean the vampires knew where Robert lived and he didn't keep quiet or anything so how come there was no interaction before?

Comment: Just speculation, but I had always assumed they needed time to build their new society before they got around to deal with the vampire-hunting menace. After all, they needed to clean up with their braindead cousins first (the revived dead) and lay some ground rules and all that. Neville was probably not their first priority.

Comment: And how come he didn't come across any talking vampire during his 3 year isolation? I mean, the living vampires even before forming a society most have walked around during the night, no one came to Robert's house?